# Difference between /usr/include/sys and /usr/include/linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, header-file

Well, obviously there is a difference, but I'm curious about the rational behind why some things go under /usr/include/sys and others go under /usr/include/linux, and have the same header file name? Does this have something to do with POSIX vx non-POSIX?

Also, I've managed to populate /usr/include/linux with headers on my Fedora system by grabbing a the kernel-headers package, is there a standard package name for me to get header files that go under /usr/include/sys? I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The headers under `/usr/include/linux` and under `/usr/include/asm*` are distributed with the Linux kernel. The other headers (`/usr/include/sys/*.h`, `/usr/include/bits/*.h`, and many more) are distributed with the C library (the [GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/), also known as glibc, on all non-embedded Linux systems). There's a little [explanation in the glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Linux.html).

Note that `/usr/include/linux` and `/usr/include/asm` should contain the headers that were used when compiling the C library, not the headers from the running kernel. Otherwise, if some constants or data structures changed, there will be an inconsistency between the compiled program and the C library, which is likely to result in a crash or worse. (If the headers match the C library but the C library doesn't match the kernel, what actually happens is that the kernel is designed to keep a stable ABI and must detect that it's called under a different ABI and interpret syscall arguments accordingly. The kernel must do this for statically compiled programs anyway.)

I remember a heated debate between Debian and Red Hat a while (a decade?) ago on the `/usr/include/linux` issue; apparently each side is sticking to its position. (As far as I understand it, Debian is right, as explained above.) Debian currently distributes `/usr/include/linux` and friends in the [`linux-libc-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/linux-libc-dev) package, which is compiled from kernel sources but not upgraded with the kernel. Kernel headers are in version-specific packages providing the [`linux-headers-2.6`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/linux-headers-2.6) metapackage; this is what you need to compile a module for a particular kernel version.

The package you're looking for is the C library headers. I don't know what it's called, but you can find out with `yum provides /usr/include/sys/types.h`.

Comment: The answer to the last bit is `glibc-headers`.